# Analyzing HTTP headers in Firebug

Tags: cookies, http-headers

I was just trying to analyse all the [HTTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol) header fields in Firefox plugin - [Firebug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firebug_%28software%29). First I logged out from Stack Overflow and then cleared all the cookies from my browser.

Then I went to the Stack Overflow's home page. I mean while saw the HTTP request and response header fields. This is what I saw:

```
Response Headers
Via    1.0 proxy_server
Content-Length    135
Date    Mon, 05 Mar 2012 06:01:33 GMT
Content-Type    application/json
Cache-Control    private
X-Cache    MISS from sampark.ncb.ernet.in


Request Headers
Host    stackoverflow.com
User-Agent    Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0; rv:12.0a2) Gecko/20120303 Firefox/12.0a2
Accept    application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Language    en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding    gzip, deflate
Proxy-Connection    keep-alive
X-Requested-With    XMLHttpRequest
Referer    http://stackoverflow.com/
Cookie    __qca=P0-383120279-1330927291125; __utma=140029553.974890682.1330927291.1330927291.1330927291.1; __utmb=140029553.1.10.1330927291; __utmc=140029553; __utmz=140029553.1330927291.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); gauthed=1
```

There is a cookie included in the request header. But as I said I have removed all the cookies from my browser. How is the cookie included in the request? What is actually happening here?

I did as Andy Davies told. I first cleared all the cookies, restarted Firefox and then went to `www.stackoverflow.com`. Firebug shows this:

```
   GET http://stackoverflow.com/tags/ios/subscriber-info?_=1331946084371
```

The headers for the above request contained:

```
Cache-Control    private
Content-Encoding    gzip
Content-Length    390
Content-Type    text/html; charset=utf-8
Date    Sat, 17 Mar 2012 01:01:19 GMT
Vary    Accept-Encoding<Br>

Request Headers
Accept    text/html, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Encoding    gzip, deflate
Accept-Language    en-us,en;q=0.5
Connection    keep-alive
Cookie    __utma=140029553.1336172974.1331946082.1331946082.1331946082.1; __utmb=140029553.1.10.1331946082; __utmc=140029553; __utmz=140029553.1331946082.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); __qca=P0-115511794-1331946081644; gauthed=1
Host    stackoverflow.com
Referer    http://stackoverflow.com/
User-Agent    Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0; rv:12.0a2) Gecko/20120303 Firefox/12.0a2
X-Requested-With    XMLHttpRequest
```

If this is not the first request, then why is it not showing the first request?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you restart the browser after clearing the cookies as, from my memory, some browsers don't clear the cookies for any sites currently open?

The snippet you've posted looks like a [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) response part way through loading the page, so it is not the initial request for the HTML page.

When the HTML page would have been requested again, the Google Analytics cookie (which is what you've got above) would have been resent, so any subsequent components on the page will also get the cookie too.

Comment: I will try that and let you know.

Comment: Don't Google Analytics cookie's get cleared when clearing all th cookies?

Comment: Yes clearing the cookies should remove the GA cookie. What you need to do is look at the headers for the first request for the page i.e. the html, to check that it has no cookie set, as once that request is made the cookie will be set.

Comment: The request headers in the question are the for the first request only. As soon as I cleared the cookies, I made went to stackoverflow.com.

Comment: I can't see how it can be the first request as it's an XHR / AJAX request, it's also got a referrer which indicates the snippet isn't the first request.

Comment: Then what is happening? Honestly, I cleared all the cookies and only then went to stack overflow.

Comment: I reckon you've posted the headers for request #15 of the following waterfall - http://www.webpagetest.org/result/120316_1J_5268d04c3e78c5c4577ac72984a579dc/1/details/

Comment: I have tried it again and this time I also copied the request url. The headers are not for request#15(http://stackoverflow.com/users/login/global/request) but for http://stackoverflow.com/tags/ios/subscriber-info?_=1331946084371. I have edited my question along with the headers. Please see it.

Comment: But again that's not the page that's served when you type http://stackoverflow.com into a browser but an ajax request the html page makes. You're not filtering in Firebug are you?

Comment: And by filetering I mean the second item on this page http://getfirebug.com/network i.e. do you have XHR checked?

Comment: You are right firebug does not show http requests at all. I am not sure of it but I think it cannot be used to to view http request when going from one site to other.

Comment: I have one more question. Does the 'X-Requested-With    XMLHttpRequest' in the request header appear when you send a xmlhttprequest. I am using ajax to get the users location in my web page. But when I exmamined the request header in firebug, the line 'X-Requested-With    XMLHttpRequest' was not included.

Comment: jQuery sets the "X-Requested-With:    XMLHttpRequest" header. Just above the waterfall in Firebug there's a line that says "Clear | Persist | All | HTML | CSS | JS | XMR | Images | Flash | Media" what happens when you click on "All" and re-run the waterfall?

Comment: So you only see the XHR requests? What happens if you try it in Chrome?

Comment: Developer tools - Right Click, Inspect Element > Network  - Need to refresh the page with it open

Comment: Yes chrome shows http requests and this time the request headers do not contain the cookies once go to stack overflow for the 'first' time after clearing the cookies. Thank you:). I will accept your answer. But please tell me if it is possible to set request header as 'xmlhttprequest' in ajax?

Comment: By creating a xmlhttprequest object and then using it send a get request. Then to set the header-call the setRequestHeader("X-Requested-With","XMLHttpRequest")

Comment: It does not work and to add to that the request itself is never sent,if I set the header manually.

Comment: I'd open a new question and include your code in it - it'll get more eyeballs that just us discussing it in a comment thread.